# F# new project structure for .Net Framework (similar to .Net Core) is missing packages.config

Tags: .net, f#, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have an F# project and although it is .NET Framework the project structure is the same as .NET Core and it is missing the packages.config file. The problem that I have is that when I download nuget packages they are stored in a global folder

> C:\Users\...\.nuget\packages

How can I change the Nuget folder to use one in my solution? I use visual studio 2019 if that matters.

Comment: .NET SDK-style projects don't use `packages.config`. By default, everything is a packagereference unless you use paket. It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish by having nuget packages stored elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use a new nuget.config file with globalPackagesFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file) which will be applied to the whole project.

**1)** create a file called `nuget.config` under your solution folder

[image]

**2)** add these on that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="packages" />
    </config>

</configuration>
```

**3)** then close VS and then restart your solution to enable that file. And your whole solution will install the packages into the packages folder of the solution rather than the global folder.